# What is the gradient of $f(x) := \langle v , F(x) v \rangle$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to S^n$ be differentiable function at point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Where $S^n$ is the space of all symmetric matrices with usual Euclidian (trace) norm. Assume $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fix vector. Define the real valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^n  \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \langle  v , F(x) v \rangle$.

My question:  Is the any nice representation of $\nabla f(x)$ in terms of derivative of $F$?

Comment: Using the definition of the directional derivative you obtain $\partial_i f(x) = \langle v, \partial_i F(x) v \rangle$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand the derivative of $F$ not as a linear Transformation. but a matrix. I feel like we can view $DF(x)$ as a  cubic  $n \times n \times n $ matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the $i^{th}$ component of the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is just the $i^{th}$ partial derivative $(\partial _if)(x)$, and by the chain rule it can be calculated as
\begin{align}
(\partial_if)(x) = \left\langle v, (\partial_iF)(x) \cdot v \right\rangle
\end{align}

We can also convey the same information in the language of Frechet/total derivatives as follows: $df_x: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is that linear map such that for every $\xi \in \Bbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align}
df_x(\xi) = \left\langle v, dF_x(\xi) \cdot v \right\rangle
\end{align}